# How can pages be added to web site

Tags: asp.net, security

I have an number (around 20) of ASP.net 3.5 web sites running a various shared hosting platforms.  Over the past week, several 'un-authorised' web pages have been added to four of these web sites (3x web forms, 1xMVC3).  These pages are static .html or .aspx files either promoting fashion goods or redirecting the user to sites that does.  The files are typically stored in a common folder such as '/css' or '/members'.

The sites themselves have a fairly low technology user interaction - maybe a simple text 'contact us' form and that's about it.

Interestingly, or perhaps confusingly, all the hacked sites are running on the same web server, with the same hosting company, but I didn't want to read too much into this - too easy to blame the hosting company.  The other 16 web sites (on other server, with other hosts) are, so far, clean.

I have run each site against https://asafaweb.com/ and all sites come up clean.  I appreciate this is no guarantee as to their robustness, but I felt it was a start.

My question/ignorance regards how can files be added to a web site.  In my naivety I had assumed this could only be achieved via FTP or a coded file upload (with corresponding existing server-side support), but I suspect this is not the case.

I appreciate that without knowing full details of the sites and technologies used it would be impossible to prescribe a solution, but I am hoping that perhaps someone could point me in the direction of where to look first or maybe otherv tools that I might use to try and find vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The hint here is that they're all on the same server so take a look at all the possible ways that your server can be accessed. Check the dates the files were created and take a look at Event/FTP Log at those specific times and see if anything unusual is listed.

Also does your sites contain an Admin Control Panel that could have been hacked?

Comment: Thanks Ahmad.  The hosting company does not provide a Control Panel - all site configuration is achieved via email request.  I will ask them for the logs and see what they say.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the only way files could be uploaded is via the Control panel or FTP (rather than some other kind of mechanism)?